# compute a minimal set of integers which intersects a given set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, integer, cluster-analysis, intersection

Given a (finite) set of intervals [a_i, b_i], where a_i <= b_i are integers, I'd like an algorithm to compute a minimal (in cardinality) set C of integers that intersects each interval.

In case some readers are distracted by the interval notation above, this problem is not about non-integer numbers.

If this is a known problem, even if it an NP-complete one, that would be useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a O(n logn) solution.

The first step is to sort the intervals, according to the values of the end `b`.

Then, for each interval considered according to this order, the corresponding `b` value is added, but only if this interval is not already intersected by a point. This is simply checked by comparing the value of its `a` parameter with the value of the last selected `b` point.

This second step has a complexity O(n). The overall complexity is then dominated by the sorting complexity O(n logn).

Here is a simple C++ implementation to illustrate the simplicity of the algorithm.

**Output:**

```
Intervals before sorting: [2, 4] [0, 3] [6, 7] [3, 3] [3, 5]
Intervals after sorting: [0, 3] [3, 3] [2, 4] [3, 5] [6, 7]
set of points: 3 7
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct Interval {
    int a, b;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Interval& x) {
        os << '[' << x.a << ", " << x.b << ']';
        return os;
    }
    friend bool operator< (const Interval& v1, const Interval& v2) {return v1.b < v2.b;}
};

template <typename T>
void print (const std::vector<T> &x, const std::string& str = "") {
    std::cout << str;
    for (const T& i: x) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

std::vector<int> min_intersection (std::vector<Interval>& interv) {
    std::vector<int> points;
    std::sort (interv.begin(), interv.end());
    print (interv, "Intervals after sorting: ");    
    if (interv.size() == 0) return points;
    int last_point = interv[0].a - 1;
    for (auto& seg: interv) {
        if (seg.a <= last_point) continue;
        last_point = seg.b;
        points.push_back (last_point);
    }
    return points;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Interval> interv = {{2, 4}, {0, 3}, {6, 7}, {3, 3}, {3, 5}};
    print (interv, "Intervals before sorting: ");
    auto points = min_intersection (interv);
    print (points, "set of points: ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A simpler, more efficient solution, with a clearer explanation and with a slick c++ implementation!

Comment: @sitiposit Thank you. Code corrected to deal with the case of an empty input.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is off the top of my head, but it looks reasonable to me.

We have a set Is of 'intervals'. Each I in Is is { n in N | a<=n<=b}. We want set C of integers such that for all I in Is there is c in C with c in I, and indeed we want the C of minimal cardinality

a/  Suppose I in Is is [a,a]. Then we must have a in C.
So let

```
C0 = {a in N | [a,a] in Is}
Is1 = { I in Is | for all c in C0, c not in I }
```

If we can find a solution C1 for Is1, C0 union C1 is a solution for Is

b/  Let I be in Is and suppose

```
Js = { J in Is | I subset J }.
```

Then we can throw away all the Js. For if C is a solution for Is\Js then since there is a c in C with c in I, then c in K for all K in Js, so C is a solution for Is.

To implement this, sort Is by a then b. Suppose I is the least element, and J its successor.
If a(I)==a(J) then we must have b(I)<=b(J) and so I subset J, and we throw away J, and move on to consider I and the successor of J
If a(I)<a(J) and b(J)<=b(I) then J subset I and we throw away I, and move on to consider J and its successor.

After this we have that for each I in Is with successor J,

```
a(I) < a(J) and b(I) < b(J).
```

If Is is now just one interval, we choose any element of the unique element in Is and stop.

Let I be the least interval in Is, and let

```
Js = { J in Is | a(J)<=b(I)}.
```

If Js is empty we choose any element of I, remove I from Is and continue.

Otherwise let k = b(I). Then k in I; if J in Js then

```
a(j)<=b(I)<b(J)
```

so k in J. Moreover for J != I and J not in Js, I and J are disjoint, so no element of I can be in more elements of Is than is k.
We add k to C, remove I and the Js from Is, and continue.

Comment: I struggled a bit to parse your solution (it's dense, not unclear) but it seems to be correct. Moreover, it seems to work in O(n^2), where n is the number of intervals. I suspect that's optimal. 

I plan to implement this (I need it for something else). If it doesn't work, I'll come back and revisit this comment. 

"off the top of my head" .... WOW!